# How does a JMS Topic Subscriber in a clustered application server recieve messages?

Tags: jms, load-balancing, publish-subscribe, cluster-computing, subscriber

Suppose I created a JMS Topic (PropertiesTopic) with one subscriber (PropertiesSubscriber). PropertiesSubscriber is running in a load balanced application server cluster as shown in the picture below.

[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/be28c03781.png](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/be28c03781.png)

When a message is delivered to PropertiesTopic, do all the instances of PropertiesSubscriber running on different app servers get that message or does the message get delivered to only one PropertiesSubscriber instance running on an app server determined by the load balancer?

Comment: The subscriber is an MDB (message-driven EJB)?

Comment: Lets suppose that each subscriber is an MDB. Would it make a difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the instances of PropertiesSubscriber running on different app servers **WILL** get that message. Even if there are multiple listeners on the same app server for the topic, all the listeners will get the message.

Answer (score 3):

[JMS 2.0 introduces *shared subscriptions*](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/jms2messaging-1954190.html). These allow multiple consumers (ex: on different nodes of a cluster) to share a single Topic subscription.  Only one of the consumers sharing a subscription will get each message.

To designate multiple consumers as sharing a subscription, they need to use the [same sharedSubscriptionName](https://jms-spec.java.net/2.0/apidocs/javax/jms/JMSContext.html#createSharedConsumer(javax.jms.Topic,%20java.lang.String))

Comment: How can we load-balance the messages in JMS1.1 ?